# use drop-down menu for linking pages in HTML in site.google

Tags: html, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

I want to use the dropdown menu on **site.google** to link different pages, but I don't know what to
write inside the **value** field in order to make this code functioning well. Could you please assist me to figure out how I can do that!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <form>
 <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
 <option value='none' selected>Choose a theme</option>
 <option value="what do I have to write here!">Page 1</option>
 <option value="#what do I have to write here!">Page 2</option>
 <option value="#what do I have to write here!">Page 3</option>
 </select>
 <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
 </form>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 function goToNewPage()
 {
    var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if(url != 'none') {
        window.location = url;
    }
   }
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Isn't all of the page creation and navigation built into each site?

Comment: yes, but I would like to use this method of the dropdown menu inside some pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)  and click it or use the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function with the [`_top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) parameter. Like so:

```html
<body>

  <form>
    <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
 <option value='none' selected>Choose a theme</option>
 <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
 <option value="https://developers.google.com/">Developers</option>
 <option value="https://developers.google.com/apps-script">Apps Script</option>
 </select>
    <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    const list = document.getElementById('list')
  function goToNewPage(){
    // Alternative 1 window.open(list.value, '_top')
    // Alternative 2
    const a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = list.value
    a.target = '_blank'
    a.click()
  }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is quite helpful, but what we can do if I don't want new windows to be opened instead I want to be in the same window, not a new tab?

Comment: Just remove the `a.target = '_blank'` line

Comment: I have removed the line but still, I get a new tab

Comment: Remember to update the deployment, I just tested and it is working. Or just use the `window.open(list.value, '_top')`

Comment: **window.open(list.value, '_top')** for this method which lines I need to remove ?

Comment: Just use the `window.open(list.value, '_top')` the rest is not necessary

Comment: I don't know what is wrong here, but the  `window.open(list.value, '_top')`  method doesn't bring anything for me!

Comment: Not reproducible on my side, the both methods work as expected